# Flex, Mozilla и абсолютно позиционированные элементы

Tags: html, css, flexbox, firefox

Давно встречаю данный баг в Мозилле но так и не нашел решения как его победить.
Итак, есть родительский блок с тремя дочерними элементами:

```html
<ul class="parent">
 <li class="child-1"></li>
 <li class="child-2"></li>
 <li class="child-3"></li>
</ul>
```

Блок `.child-3` имеет `position:absolute` и по логике вырван из потока. На родительский блок задаем `display:flex` и, например, `justify-content:space-between`.
 Все браузеры включая IE11 отрабатывают правильно: `.child-1` и `.child-2` разъезжаются к противоположным краям `.parent`. 
Но в Mozilla это не так: она резервирует место для `.child-3`, которого в потоке нет, и из-за этого `.child-2` болтается где-то посередине родительского блока. Более того, если `.child-3` заменить на `.parent:after` со свойствами `content:""; position:absolute` то ничего не изменится - под псевдоэлемент браузер все так же будет резервировать место и рассчитывать положение элементов с учетом абсолютно-позиционированного элемента.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Почитайте статью [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: как минимум нужно еще добавить css, что юзеры не пытались в догадках

Answer (score 2):

Решил такую проблему, отказавшись от `flexbox` в пользу `display: table`.

Было 3 кнопки, расположенных по диагонали при помощи `justify-content: space-between; align-items: center` и крайним элементам были даны `align-self: flex-start / flex-end` соответственно. Потом в блок были добавлены скрытые прозрачные абсолютно спозиционированные кнопки, и в мозилле верстка сломалась (выделялось место в потоке под скрытые кнопки, и центральная кнопка смещалась) Пришлось вынести 3 изначальные кнопки в таблицу (каждая в своей строке), и все заработало, как надо.

Comment: Постарайтесь дать немного более развернутый ответ, чтобы его попросту не удалили

Comment: Вот это развернутый ответ. Внесите правку, чтобы другие пользователи без труда могли разобраться с решением проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать в родительском блоке: `flex-wrap: wrap`, а в `child-ах` указать их размеры. Используйте в данном случае не `display: flex`, а `display: inline-flex`.

Линейное построение, с переносом при указании размеров, перенесет второй элемент влево при `justify-content: space-between`, если первый элемент занимает пространство столько, что второй по своим размерам туда не влезет и не будет никакого центрирования второго элемента.

Ширину элемента лучше указывать через `flex-basis`.